# Send Email through Django on DotCloud

Tags: django, email, django-admin, smtp, dotcloud

If I want to send email through Django and DotCloud, how should I do it?
Should I send it through Django, https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/, or DotCloud, http://docs.dotcloud.com/services/smtp/? I want to be able to send out batch emails through the Admin interface in Django. Is django-mailer (won't let me post link) what I want to send through the admin?

---

**EDIT I:**
I guess in general I was curious if anyone had any implementations of SMTP emailing through the Django Admin.

---

**EDIT II:** I actually decided to try django-newsletter (won't let me post link), since I want to send bulk emails to custom lists from the admin.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't fully understood the advantage of using dotCloud's SMTP service.

I have sent emails using the regular Django way (I put the right hosts, username, etc for a GMail account in `settings.py` and used the [regular functions/classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/email/)) and have had no problems.

I have found [admin actions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/actions/) extremely useful. Actions are very easy to write and I am sure it's possible to write one that sends emails.

Comment: Thanks so much for the link to admin actions. They seem to be just what I am looking for. I decided that using [celery](http://celeryproject.org/) would be best for me, so that I can send bulk emails in the background.

Comment: DotCloud SMTP service is useful if you need to queue outgoing mails *and* require scaling. If you queue an outgoing mail on a web front-end, and then scale down that web front-end, the outgoing mail will be lost (if it's still in queue when you scale down). Granted, that's not something you need every day, but when you do, it's convenient :-)